# Force user to enter number in a SearchView

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

I am using a SearchView on action bar in my app and I defined it as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="@string/search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

If it was editText, I could simply write android:inputType="Number" or something like that to force the user to enter number but I could not find such an option for an item. I do not want to check manually if the user entered a number to search view, I want to show the user a keyboard that contains only numbers. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: menu item cannot tak text inputs

Comment: you can set from Java code

Comment: Your comment is correct jagapathi. I found an answer and posted it below in case anyone else is stuck on this.

Answer (score 3):

I found an easy solution for this. The only thing one needs to do is to use the method setInputType() inside onCreateOptionsMenu

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.music, menu);
        SearchView searchView= (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        return true;
    }
```